# Where do these values of R, G and B coefficients come from?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Grayscale_image#C.23

```
Bitmap tImage = new Bitmap("spectrum.bmp");

for (int x = 0; x < tImage.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < tImage.Height; y++)
    {
        Color tCol = tImage.GetPixel(x, y);

        // L = 0.2126·R + 0.7152·G + 0.0722·B 
        double L = 0.2126 * tCol.R + 0.7152 * tCol.G + 0.0722 * tCol.B;
        tImage.SetPixel(x, y, Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(L),
 Convert.ToInt32(L), Convert.ToInt32(L)));
    }
}

// Save
tImage.Save("spectrum2.bmp");
```

Where do we find `// L = 0.2126·R + 0.7152·G + 0.0722·B` these values?

Comment: [wikipedia on grayscale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find that information in [ITU (International Telecommunication Union)](http://www.itu.int/) Recommendation `ITU BT.709`

[Parameter values for the HDTV standards for production and international programme exchange](http://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/bt/R-REC-BT.709-6-201506-I!!PDF-E.pdf)

See page 4

You can see old versions [here](http://www.itu.int/rec/R-REC-BT.709/en)